# Dataframe convert factors to numerical error

Tags: r, dataframe, numeric, factors

I am trying to convert factors from a data-frame to numeric using the commands

```
data[] <- lapply (data, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))
```

But it keeps asking me for more coding. What am I doing wrong?
The data-frame is named `data` and it consists of 50 rows and 2 columns. Will this command change every variable in numeric right? Or shall I do something else?

screenshot after using         'dput'          at https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IJZN.png

Comment: Can you  add any warnings / messages / errors to your question please. If possible also add the results of `dput(data[ , 1:5])`. Note `as.numeric(as.character(x))`  wont always return an integer as it depends on how the variables in data are stored (it may return NA)

Comment: See if it works with `map_if` from `purrr` package. `data %>%map_if(is.factor, as.numeric)` . Note: you would also need `dplyr` for the pipe operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you add `)` at the end of your code?